# bash float comparison and (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, floating-point, comparison, bc

I have this piece of code where I am getting `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` from the third line:

```
valueInFloat=printf "%.2g" $temp
tempFloat=printf "%.1f" $value2
compare_result=`echo "$tempFloat < $valueInFloat" |bc -l`
if [[ -z $compare_result ]]
then ...
```

I am trying to do float value comparison in `bash`.

Note that, if I comment out the third line and put `compare_result=0`, the error goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are situations in which `printf` can generate floating point values that `bc` won't recognise. Specifically, something like:

```
pax> printf "%.2g\n" 42456456457357357
4.2e+16
pax> echo '4.2e+16 > 1.0' | bc -l
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I suggest you stick with the `%f` variant. It will always generate the form `[−]999.999` as per the ISO C standard, which `bc` will have no trouble with (unless you start getting into infinities or NaNs). The `%g` variant generates either that format or the `%e` format `[−]9.999e±99` depending on the value and precision requested.

In addition, your test is wrong. The `-z` test will be true if the string is empty, and your string will either be `1` or `0` depending on the result of the comparison. A better test would be (assuming you wanted to rest if the test was positive:

```
if [[ ${compare_result} -eq 1 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

Either of `$tempFloat` or `$valueInFloat` has no value.

Comment: this is only piece of script, value in these variable will be achieved 
 valueInFloat=`printf "%.2g" $temp`
tempFloat=`printf "%.1f" $value2`

Comment: Thanks you solved the problem...I am using different format specifiers that is causing the problem .